# Logitech M720 Triathlon does not automatically reconnect when switching back to my ubuntu device

Tags: mouse, bluetooth, logitech

I am using two ubuntu devices (1 laptop and 1 PC). I am using my unifying receiver for my PC and it is working. However, when I switch to my laptop, the mouse does not automatically connect. I have to go to the bluetooth settings and turn the connection to the mouse off then on again.

When I try using bluetooth (no usb receiver) for both my laptop and PC, I get the same issue for both.

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Same here since Nov 2023. Before it worked. After every disconnecting the mouse i have to remove the device an repair it.